# Does the cellar need to be aired regularly even though the dehumidifier is running 24x7?

Tags: basement, dehumidifier

I recently got a dehumidifier which collects an amazing amount of water.

Because of the damp cellar, I had previously aired twice a week. Do I need to continue to air it even though the dehumidifier collects a lot of water and is running 24x7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dehumidifier does its job, by recycling the air and removing humidity.

However it only recycles the air, so it is up to you to let fresh air in.

Of course if the humidity outside is much higher, the dehumidifier will have to start all over.

Comment: yeah, if you're worried about radon for instance the dehumidifier won't help with that.